# utop and printing constructors

Tags: ocaml, utop

When loading up code in `utop` (or `dune utop`) and printing any data constructor like `Bin.Stop` with `#show Bin.Stop;;` I get a crash.

```
utop # #show Bin.Stop;;
>> Fatal error: Ident.rename Bin.nat
Fatal error: exception Misc.Fatal_error

~ via  v4.12.0 took 4m41s
❯
```

While `ocaml` does not crash.
Is this a bug or is there an obvious reason why that would be illegal ?

```ml
(* SOTypeLevelNat.ml *)
module Bin : sig
  type stop = Qasdpaokdsap

  type 'a zero = Sasddkasdo

  type 'a one = Zoldjsfoij

  type _ nat =
    | Stop : 'stop nat
    | Times2      : 'n nat -> 'n zero nat
    | Times2Plus1 : 'n nat -> 'n one nat
end = struct
  type stop = Qasdpaokdsap

  type 'a zero = Sasddkasdo

  type 'a one = Zoldjsfoij

  type _ nat =
    | Stop : 'stop nat
    | Times2      : 'n nat -> 'n zero nat
    | Times2Plus1 : 'n nat -> 'n one nat
end
```

```
utop # #use  "SOTypeLevelNat.ml";;
module Peano :
  sig
    type 'a s = S
    type z = Z
    type 'n nat = Zero : 'a nat | Succ : 'n nat -> 'n s nat
  end
module Bin :
  sig
    type stop = Qasdpaokdsap
    type 'a zero = Sasddkasdo
    type 'a one = Zoldjsfoij
    type _ nat =
        Stop : 'stop nat
      | Times2 : 'n nat -> 'n zero nat
      | Times2Plus1 : 'n nat -> 'n one nat
  end
```

printing a type, say, the `nat` works just fine

```
utop # #show Bin.nat;;
type nonrec _ nat =
    Stop : 'stop Bin.nat
  | Times2 : 'n Bin.nat -> 'n Bin.zero Bin.nat
  | Times2Plus1 : 'n Bin.nat -> 'n Bin.one Bin.nat
```

Comment: Indeed that is a bug in utop, I can reproduce it (utop 2.7.0 for OCaml 4.12.0) with any constructor, so it is nothing specific to this code. `#show Seq.Nil` or `type t = A ;; #show A` are MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatal errors with toplevel directives that happen in `utop` and not `ocaml` are bugs in `utop`.

Indeed, `utop` partially reimplements the driver logic of the OCaml REPL and it can happen that utop's code ends up slightly out-of-date with the underlying OCaml's compiler libraries.

Please report issues like this at: https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop/issues

Comment: I hope the edit's ok - it somehow ended up in the very low quality queue (even though I can see that it is an actual answer - I don't have the domain expertise to know whether it's accurate or not, but that question should be settled by voting, not the VLQ queue).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have reverted some of the modal qualifiers: due to the structure of utop, if an error shows up in one of the REPL directive, the error cannot really be located  in the user code.

Comment: So "probably" should be "definitely" in this case? Further proof that I'm not particularly familiar with the technology in question I guess.

Comment: Yes. This is more a generic rule for REPLs(aka interactive interpreters): if an error happens on a directive which is sent directly to the REPL as a software, this an error of the REPL as a software and not an error in the code being interpreted.